# Assigning variables from a matrix in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I think I'm incorrectly accessing and assigning variables from a matrix.  I understand that arrays, matrices, and tables are different in R.  What I want to end up with is an array of values called "c" that has either a 1 or 2 assigning an element from input to either Mew(number 1) or Mewtwo(number 2.  I also want the distance from Mew to all other points in an array called dMew as well as dMewtwo an array of the distance from Mewtwo to all other elements in input.  What I end up with is NA_real_ for all variables except input.  There is a lot of great information on accessing rows or columns of various data structures in R but I'm interested in accessing single elements.  Any advice would be most helpful.  I apologize if this has been answered before but I couldn't find it anywhere.

```
#Read input from a csv data file
input = read.csv("~/Desktop/Engineering/iris.csv",head=FALSE)
input = input[c(0:3)]
input = as.matrix(input)

#set random centroids
Mew = input[1,1]
Mewtwo = input[nrow(input),ncol(input)]

#Determine Distance
dist <- function(x, y) {
  return(sqrt((x - y)^2))
}

#Determine the clusters
dMew = matrix(,nrow(input), ncol(input))
dMewtwo = matrix(,nrow(input), ncol(input))
c = matrix(,nrow(input), ncol(input))
for (i in 1:nrow(input)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(input)) {
    dMew[i,j] = dist(Mew, input[i,j])
    dMewtwo[i,j] = dist(Mewtwo, input[i,j])
    if (dMew[i,j] > dMewtwo[i,j]) {
      c[i,j] = 2
    } else {
      c[i,j] = 1
    }
  }
}

#Update the centroids
Mew = mean(dMew)
Mewtwo = mean(dMewtwo)
```

Comment: Your `for` loops only iterate over `nrow(input)` and `ncol(input)` instead of `1:nrow(input)` and `1:ncol(input)`. Try making your code reproducible and reduce it to the main problem, we don't have access to your data source for example.

Comment: Yes, I noticed after I posted.

Comment: Your `dist` function returns `x - y` because you forgot to use `sum`. Could you provide some data to work with?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem running the code with the following input:

```
input = data.frame(V1=1:5,V2=1:5,V3=1:5)
```

so it seems to be a problem related to your data. Also you should avoid using "c" as a variable name and note that dist() is already a function in the stats package. Also, you can avoid the for-loops by using apply() and ifelse():

```
#Read input from a csv data file
input = data.frame(V1=1:5,V2=1:5,V3=1:5)
input = input[c(1:3)]
input = as.matrix(input)

#set random centroids
Mew = input[1,1]
Mewtwo = input[nrow(input),ncol(input)]

#Determine Distance
dist.eu <- function(x, y) {
  return(sqrt((x - y)^2))
}

dMew<-apply(input,c(1,2),dist.eu,Mew)
dMewtwo<-apply(input,c(1,2),dist.eu,Mewtwo)

c.mat<-ifelse(dMew > dMewtwo,2,1)
c.mat
```